# Deserialize struct using Newtonsoft.Json in Unity, the struct is from an .dll file imported to unity ';Assets' folder

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, dll, dllexport

So, basically I have a class library named Shared.dll that build and serialize with newtonsoft.Json, and I want to deserialize the class/struct inside .dll file.

Unity version: 2022.3.f1.

**PlayerData.cs** (From Shared.dll) - Shared.IPlayerData

```
public interface IPlayerData
{
    public string PlayerId { get; }
    ICloudSaveData CloudSaveData { get; set; }
    ICurrencyData CurrencyData { get; set; }
    IInventoryData InventoryData { get; set; }
}
```

**PlayerData.cs** (From Shared.dll) - Shared.PlayerData that implement interface above

```
[Serializable]
public struct PlayerData : IPlayerData
{
    public PlayerData(ICloudSaveData cloudSaveData, ICurrencyData currencyData, IInventoryData inventoryData) : this()
    {
        CloudSaveData = cloudSaveData;
        CurrencyData = currencyData;
        InventoryData = inventoryData;
    }

    [JsonProperty] public string PlayerId { get; private set; }
    [JsonProperty] public ICloudSaveData CloudSaveData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty] public ICurrencyData CurrencyData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty] public IInventoryData InventoryData { get; set; }

    public PlayerData SetPlayerId(string id)
    {
        this.PlayerId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

Inside Unity Engine, I'm also using newtonsoft.Json and VContainer.

**LifeTimeScope.cs** (Script created in Unity)

```
protected override void Configure(IContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // Register collections
    builder.Register<IPlayerData, PlayerData>(Lifetime.Singleton)
        .WithParameter<ICloudSaveData>(new CloudSaveData())
        .WithParameter<ICurrencyData>(new CurrencyData())
        .WithParameter<IInventoryData>(new InventoryData());
    builder.Register<HeroDataCollection>(Lifetime.Singleton);
    
    // Register other Components
}
```

Then it return an error said as below:

> TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100001b from typeref (expected class 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
> System.MonoCustomAttrs.IsDefined (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0)
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.IsDefined (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0)

This is how I deserialize those object

**CustomDataConverter.cs** (Shared.dll)

```
public class CustomDataConverter<T1, T2> : CustomCreationConverter<T1> where T2 : T1, new()
{
    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }

    public override T1 Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new T2();
    }
}
```

Deserialize inside NUnit Test Project is worked and return correct object. But if I use below code to deserialize inside unity, it'll return an error

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerData>(t,
                    new CustomDataConverter<ICloudSaveData, CloudSaveData>(), new CustomDataConverter<ICurrencyData, CurrencyData>(),
                    new CustomDataConverter<IInventoryData, InventoryData>(), new CustomDataConverter<IPlayerEquipment, PlayerEquipment>(),
                    new CustomDataConverter<IPlayerHero, PlayerHero>(), new CustomDataConverter<IPlayerChapter, PlayerChapter>(),
                    new CustomDataConverter<IState, State>(), new CustomDataConverter<IStat, StatData>(), 
                    new CustomDataConverter<IUseable, PlayerUseable>());
```

Unity Error:

> TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100001b from typeref (expected class 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
> System.MonoCustomAttrs.IsDefined (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0)
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.IsDefined (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) (at <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.IsValidCallback (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] parameters, System.Type attributeType, System.Reflection.MethodInfo currentCallback, System.Type& prevAttributeType) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetCallbackMethodsForType (System.Type type, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SerializationCallback]& onSerializing, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SerializationCallback]& onSerialized, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SerializationCallback]& onDeserializing, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SerializationCallback]& onDeserialized, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.SerializationErrorCallback]& onError) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0) Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveCallbackMethods (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Type t) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0) Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0) Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract (System.Type objectType) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0) Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0) System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) (at <6aa56e57ab504395b555cf3ed50fa53d>:0) Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[TKey,TValue].Get (TKey key) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract (System.Type type) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContract (System.Type type) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe (System.Type type) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[] converters) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[] converters) (at <761cf2a144514d2291a678c334d49e9b>:0)

The sample json string as below:

```
{
  "cloudSaveData": {
    "afkReward": {
      "cards": [],
      "cashy": 0,
      "equipments": [],
      "gem": 0,
      "useables": []
    },
    "afkStartTime": "2023-07-13T20:44:29",
    "combatPower": 0,
    "currentChapter": {
      "0": {
        "currentState": 1,
        "unlockChapterTime": "2023-07-14T03:44:29.7931243+07:00"
      }
    },
    "experience": 0,
    "heroOwned": {
      "0": {
        "armor": null,
        "count": 0,
        "helmet": null,
        "level": 1,
        "shoes": null,
        "weapon": null
      }
    },
    "level": 0,
    "maxExperience": 0,
    "playerEquipment": {
      "0": {
        "experience": 0,
        "isEquipped": false,
        "level": 1,
        "maxExperience": 0,
        "stats": null
      }
    },
    "playerUseable": null,
    "vip": 0,
    "vipLevel": 0
  },
  "currencyData": {
    "cashy": 0,
    "gem": 0
  },
  "inventoryData": {
    "equipments": null,
    "useables": null
  },
  "playerId": "SwhCNcE8a489qRNI9gE1m75QWskj"
}
```